# Installation problem: alongside-option

Tags: software-installation, usb-installation

I managed to start the installation process from my usb, but the system doesn't seem to recognize my current operating system and I can't launch the 'install alongside windows' option. Where is the problem?

Comment: Best to make sure Windows fast start up is off. And use Windows to shrink the NTFS partition to make unallocated space, and reboot so it can run chkdsk. Fast start up or chkdsk flags will prevent the Linux NTFS driver for fully seeing the Windows install. Most Windows now are UEFI, so be sure to boot Ubuntu live installer in UEFI mode to install in UEFI mode. https://ubuntu.com/tutorials/install-ubuntu-desktop#1-overview Some brands or models of systems may need additional UEFI or boot settings. Best to research your system.

Comment: What version of Ubuntu are you trying to install? Are you getting asked to install along side Windows?